Why is htop showing a lot of "kernel" activity?
Is it normal to see this much "kernel" activity on a server that is not currently running anything (at least at the user/application layer)?
According to this link the red portion of the core display represents "kernel threads". When I run htop on my personal laptop and work laptop, I don't see anywhere near that much red.
System information:

Hardware: Dell PowerEdge R320
CPU: Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2440 0 @ 2.40GHz
OS: Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS



I posted this same question here and got a perfect answer.

Please answer your own question and mark this question answered if it has been. And please avoid cross posting across Stack Exchange communities.

@JohnMahowald I attempted to answer my own question and it got automatically converted to a comment.

Linux modules and parameters using a lot of resources if its not configured correctly
Checking your kernel parametrs with
sysctl -p
Also using atop command for debugging and more information

How would this happen if I just did a standard install (of the OS)?

no , it's not happend , do you install any package or configure any service of linux ?
